# Basic stuff assembler (TASM)

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I'm new to assembly language and I would like to ask you the following:

> ```
>     mov ax, y
> imul z; dx:ax = y*z
> mov bx, dx
> mov cx, ax ; bx:cx = y*z
> mov ax, x
> cwd ; dx:ax = x
> sub ax, cx
> sbb dx, bx ; dx:ax = x-y*z
> ```

Why do I have to use the last code line.
What am I trying to do is to calculate x-y*z...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

If I recall my 80386 assembly (yes, it's been that long), the last line is a subtract with borrow.  This is the same as when you do subtraction by hand:  if you subtract 16 from 24, for example, you subtract 6 from 4 first.  But to do that you BORROW a 1 from the tens column and get 12-6=6 for the low order digit.  When you do the high order digit, you have to remember that you borrowed and take that into account: 10-10 =0, so the answer is 6.

When you `sub ax,cx`, the borrow flag is set if borrowing was necessary, when you `sbb dx, bx`, you adjust for the previous borrow.